# why Erlang string can't used as ets table name?

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I'm dynamic create `ets` table, so it's better avoid atom as name.
Simple use string as name, such as:
`:ets.new("aaa", [:named_table])`

But it can't be compiled:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.new("aaa", [])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're creating ETS tables dynamically, one way to do it is to create them as unnamed tables, and use the table id returned by `:ets.new` to access them:

```
iex(1)> table1 = :ets.new(:foo, [])
8212
iex(2)> table2 = :ets.new(:foo, [])
12309
iex(3)> :ets.insert(table1, {:a, 1})
true
iex(4)> :ets.insert(table2, {:a, 2})
true
iex(5)> :ets.lookup(table1, :a)
[a: 1]
iex(6)> :ets.lookup(table2, :a)
[a: 2]
```

(In Erlang/OTP 20.0, the table id is a reference instead of an integer, but it works the same way; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49633255/113848).)

Comment: Thanks. It seems I will get a reference type. BTW, Can I convert a reference to string for response a id to client? And also, I want a string convert to a pid. Or I must create another ets to record a map of `{string_name, reference}`?

Comment: There is `erlang:ref_to_list` and `erlang:list_to_ref`, but the documentation says "This BIF is intended for debugging and is not to be used in application programs", so I'd go with an explicit map from response ids to references.

Comment: even though don't know why it is not recommend. I willing follow the good practice one. Saving to map seems a normal way without a magic to hand it ;-)